# Aurelia, long list of bindables on custom element. Refactor?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have a repeating card-type custom element that is bound to JSON data pulled from an api. My current method of creating and binding the data to these cards as they are displayed works, but everything about it screams "REFACTOR" to me. Is there a better way to achieve these ends with Aurelia?

My current custom element pattern looks like this

**pager-view.html**

```
  <!-- Loop through the JSON task-data (each card contains the chosen task-data to display) -->
  <template repeat.for="task of pageData[currentPage - 1]">

    <!--Bind each tasks data to a card as we loop-->
    <card-commit

      task-data.bind="task"
      task-id.bind="task.ID"
      task-name.bind="task.name"
      project-id.bind="task.project.ID"
      project-name.bind="task.project.name"
      assigned-to.bind="task.assignedTo.name"
      successors.bind="task.successors"
      commit-status.bind="task.commitStatus"
      planned-start-date.bind="task.plannedStartDate"
      planned-comp-date.bind="task.plannedCompletionDate"
      duration.bind="task.duration"
      actual-start-date.bind="task.actualStartDate"
      commit-date.bind="task.commitDate"
      condition.bind="task.condition"
      constraint.bind="task.taskConstraint"
      constraint-date.bind="task.constraintDate"
      status.bind="task.status"
      note.bind="task.lastNote"
      note-text.bind="task.lastNote.noteText"
      note-entry-date.bind="task.lastNote.entryDate"
      note-avatar-download-url.bind="task.lastNote.owner.avatarDownloadURL"
      note-owner-name.bind="task.lastNote.owner.name"
      actual-completion-date.bind="task.actualCompletionDate"
    ></card-commit>

  </template>
```

**card-commit.ts**

```
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CardCommit {
  @bindable public taskData;
  @bindable public taskId;
  @bindable public taskName;
  @bindable public projectId;
  @bindable public projectName;
  @bindable public assignedTo;
  @bindable public successors;
  @bindable public commitStatus;
  @bindable public plannedStartDate;
  @bindable public plannedCompDate;
  @bindable public duration;
  @bindable public actualStartDate;
  @bindable public actualStartDelta;
  @bindable public commitDate;
  @bindable public condition;
  @bindable public conditionClass;
  @bindable public conditionText;
  @bindable public constraint;
  @bindable public constraintDate;
  @bindable public status;
  @bindable public note;
  @bindable public noteText;
  @bindable public noteEntryDate;
  @bindable public noteAvatarDownloadUrl;
  @bindable public noteOwnerName;
  @bindable public updateNoteText;
  @bindable public actualCompletionDate;

  constructor() {
    // ... do constructor stuff
  }

  // ... other methods etc
}
```

**card-commit.html**

```
<!-- Do all sorts of stuff with the bound data, for example... -->
<template>
  <!-- This example wouldn't really work, just demonstrating how I'm using the bound data -->
  <article data-task-id="${ taskId }">
    <ul repeat.bind="for example of task">
      <li data-example-commit="example.commitDate">${example.condition}</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</template>
```

Maybe I'm being overly nit-picky, but if feels like I should be able to define this relationship in *at least* a more compact way, specifically the long list bindings being defined (essentially) twice. But I'm just not sure how else I could achieve this and haven't been able to really find much on the subject/issue specifically.

Comment: Do these properties ever change independently, or do they always change as a group, all at once?

Comment: @AshleyGrant: If I'm understanding your question correctly, they change all at once. The purpose for the above bindings is mostly display. However, the point of the display is for the user to change certain properties independently and submit back to the API.

Comment: If they all change at once, then you could just have a single property bound in that is an object with all of these properties. Then when you need to change all of the properties, just bind in a brand new object.

Comment: That reminds me that's actually kind of a thought I had, and why `@bindable taskData` is available in the class and bound as `task-data.bind="task" ` in the template. It was a while ago I set that up so I forgot and don't remember why I abandoned that approach... but if I used that I could just use those primary bindings and then all of the main `taskData` properties would be inherently bindable as well?

Comment: Yeah, you're just passing an object in to the custom element. The custom element can use the properties of that object however it would like. Note that changing the value of any of these properties from inside the custom element will also change them on the object held by the parent, as they're both working with the same object.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. Can't believe I forgot about that in my own setup >.>

Comment: @DjH Would you be able to add an answer and close this question please? :)

Comment: @thebluefox: Yes I'm planning on it. Just been stuck working on something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can you just bind the object to a class attribute (like I did with `task-data.bind="task"` in `pager-view.html`)
- Use this object to reference what you want directly in the template.

So revised would be something like this...

**pager-view.html**

```
  <!-- Loop through the JSON task-data (each card contains the chosen task-data to display) -->
  <template repeat.for="task of pageData[currentPage - 1]">

    <!--Bind each tasks data to a card as we loop-->
    <card-commit
      task-data.bind="task"
    ></card-commit>

  </template>
```

**card-commit.ts**

```
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CardCommit {
  @bindable public taskData;

  constructor() {
    // ... do constructor stuff
  }

  // ... other methods etc
}
```

**card-commit.html**

```
<!-- Now we reference the data that we want directly on the `taskData` attribute -->
<!-- Do all sorts of stuff with the bound data, for example... -->
<template>
  <!-- This example wouldn't really work, just demonstrating how I'm using the bound data -->
  <article data-task-id="${ taskData.taskId }">
    <ul repeat.bind="for example of taskData.task">
      <li data-example-commit="example.commitDate">${example.condition}</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</template>
```

---

HOWEVER, (and maybe this is possible, but I can't find any references to it), it would be *really* nice to be able to inject/pass the `taskData` to the class constructor, sort of like this...

**pager-view.html**

```
<!--Bind each tasks data to a card as we loop-->
<card-commit
  card-commit.constructor="task"
></card-commit>
```

And then be able to merge it in the constructor of the class, maybe something like this:

**card-commit.ts**

```
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CardCommit {
  @bindable public taskData;

  constructor(taskData) {
    Object.entries(taskData).forEach(([key, val]) => {
       Object.assign(this, {[key]: val});
    });
  }

  // ... other methods etc
}
```

Then we could access the properties directly on the object, like in the initial code presented for refactor.

If I get the time to find a way to accomplish this I'll update. In the meantime, if anyone else knows how to do it, I'd gladly accept that as the answer in lieu of this.

Comment: Use the with binding to change the children's datacontext. That way you would have a minimal refactor in your card-commit.html,
see http://patrickwalters.net/aurelia-data-binding-strategies/